# Responsive scrollbar that reacts to screen size

Tags: html, css

So I have this area where I have some info and I want it to always have

```
height: 95%;
```

But why does this not work with scrollbar?

I currently try to use this CSS for it:

```
.scrollable-main-area{
    height: 80%;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

If I set a fixed height, it will work but with % height it will not. But with fixed height, some elements at the bottom will go missing when I scroll down.

Comment: Can you provide an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: Not able to put that code in public sadly. But it's just a page that has it's normal scrollbar removed, instead it has a menu on the right and depending of the item chosen, a view is created left to the menu and that view is scrollable. This wat the menu is never scroller while the main content is.

Comment: Also worth nothing maybe that the part of the page i am talking about has some dynamic content coming into it after the first load.